# How to start VPN service manually?

Tags: networking, vpn, pptp

Since this morning I cannot connect to **pptp vpn**. when I click on NetworkManager applet and select the vpn it says:

```
VPN connection fail
The VPN connection "whatever" failed because vpn service failed to start
```

I google it, but the result didn't helped me.

thanks in advance.

Comment: I think problem was for the **gtk2-module-rgba** I installed from **ppa:erik-b-andersen/rgba-gtk** I checked **History** in **ubuntu software center** and saw it was the last thing I installed before getting this error. so I removed it and reboot and now everything is fine! thanks

Comment: nmcli c down id <VPNNAME> # stop
    nmcli c up id <VPNNAME> # start

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo service openvpn start
```

Comment: getting same error!

Comment: unrecognized service.

Comment: `sudo service openvpn stop` and `sudo service openvpn start`  helped for me